# How to display placeholder in editor wysibb?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, editor

I tried to show placeholder in editor(textarea) **wysibb** like as:

```
placeholder="Text"
```

But this does not work. I have seen at wysibb documentation there is not placeholder option.

Answer (score 0):

The "textarea" of the WYSIWYG is an iframe, you have to locate the document into the iframe and add some html to that.

Comment: Can you share example?